# form $_POST error, dynamic fields

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have an error that I can't figure out...

Om my webpage there is a form that the user has the ability to add some new input fields to. If the user is submitting the form, then the optional fields is empty when the php-file is handing them, why?

HTML:

```
        <form method="post" action="newRequest.php">
            <input type="text" name="title" />
            <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="fname" value="1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ename" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="ename" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="seat" value="0" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="seat" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="fields" value="0" />
            <input type="text" id="fields" name="fields" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```

PHP:

```
if (strlen($_POST[title]) > 2) {
    $toDb[title] = $_POST[title];
} else {
    error('title');
}

$toDb[fname] = $_POST[fname];
$toDb[ename] = $_POST[ename];
$toDb[seat] = $_POST[seat];

if ($_POST[fields] > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $_POST[fields]) {
        $toDb[optional][$i] = $_POST[optional-$i];
        $i++;
    }
    $toDb[optional] = serialize($toDb[optional]);
} else {
    $toDb[optional] = 0;
}
newEvent($toDb,$dbh);
```

JQuery that is adding dynamical fields:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fields').focusout(function(){

        var fields = $('#fields').val();
        var i = 0;

        while(i < fields) {
            $('#fields').after("Valfritt fält "+(i+1)+":<input type='text' name='optional"+i+"' />");
            i++;
        }

    })
})
```

Comment: This is how you use hash arrays: `$foo["bar"] = $_POST["bar"];`, the string index should be quoted.

Comment: All your field names have duplicates; the first one gets overwritten by the second one when it gets parsed in PHP.

Comment: The duplicates is there because the first one is setting a default value that is sent to PHP if the user leaves the field empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote array indexes. It should be

```
 $toDb['optional'][$i] = $_POST['optional'.$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing commas in $_POST

```
$toDb['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$toDb['ename'] = $_POST['ename'];
$toDb['seat'] = $_POST['seat'];
```

Here is your modified code

```
if (strlen($_POST['title']) > 2) {
    $toDb['title'] = $_POST['title'];
} else {
    error('title');
}

$toDb['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$toDb['ename'] = $_POST['ename'];
$toDb['seat'] = $_POST['seat'];

if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($_POST)) {
        $toDb['optional'][$i] = $_POST['optional-'.$i];
        $i++;
    }
    $toDb['optional'] = serialize($toDb['optional']);
} else {
    $toDb['optional'] = 0;
}
newEvent($toDb,$dbh);
```

Also use count() to check if $_POST has values > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I solved it using Javascript, like this :

[add a new text field every time a button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268232/add-a-new-text-field-every-time-a-button-is-pressed/15213197#15213197)